# pagination classic asp, and button changed to hyperlinks

Tags: html, vbscript, asp-classic, pagination

I've created buttons that have been edited with css to look like hyperlinks so I can use form post instead of using querystring. I've made it so that when a button is clicked it creates a checkbox for each user. I want it so that when i change the state of the checkbox I want it to save as I'm going through different letters. I believe the problem I am having is because the "hyperlinks" are really buttons and changing the checked state of a checkbox is creating problems. I would prefer not to use JavaScript but if its the only way for me to get the results that I want then I would use java-script. Code provided below -

```
<form action="Table.asp" method="post" name="form2">
<input type="submit" name="Button" value="#" style="background:transparent;border:0;display:inline;color:#00F;text-decoration:underline;padding:0px;cursor:pointer">
<% for i = 97 to 122 %>     
     <input type="submit" name="Button" value="<%=CHR(i) %>" style="background:transparent;border:0;display:inline;color:#00F;text-decoration:underline;padding:0px;cursor:pointer;">&nbsp;
<% next %>

 </br></br></br>

 <%
    alphaB = request.form("Button")
 if alphaB <>"" then
        %>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox" value="<%=alphaB %>" <%=session("checkBox") %>>
        <%
        response.write alphaB


 end if


alphaCheck = request.form("checkBox")

if alphaCheck <>"" then
    session("checkBox") = "checked"
else
    session("checkBox") = ""
end if
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all you got wrong is the place where you set your session ...

move

```
alphaCheck = request.form("checkBox")
if alphaCheck <>"" then
    session("checkBox_"&alphaCheck) = "checked"
else
    session("checkBox_"&alphaCheck) = ""
end if 
...
<input type="checkbox" name="checkBox" value="<%=alphaB %>" <%=session("checkbox_"&alphaB ) %>/>
```

before the checkbox creation

what happen is that on the first time your session is not initialized once you hit the page

Comment: ok so that works better than before but now i have 1 last problem. The checkboxes are all setting to checked value.

Comment: u will need a different session for each checkbox session("checkbox_"&alphaB)

Comment: actualy i am wrong alphaB wont give you the right letter u will have to use alphaCheck value : session("checkbox_"&alphaCheck) something like that

Comment: and when u write the checkbox : <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox" value="<%=alphaB %>" <%=session("checkbox_"&alphaB) %>/> will fix the code in my post

Answer (score -1):

```
<!--#include file="session_check.asp"-->
<!--#include file="connection.asp"-->
<%

'    Last updated by Arun Sharma
'    last updation pourpos mintain the paging of POP closed calls
'    last updated on 6th sep. 2007`enter code here`

%>
<%
     if session("type1")=0 and session("type2") =0 then 
     response.redirect "Default.asp"
     end if
%>

<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
<meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft FrontPage 5.0">
<meta name="ProgId" content="FrontPage.Editor.Document">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">

<title>view</title>


</head>

<body>

<%
If session("type") ="sa" Then
 %>
 <p><!--#include file="header_sa.asp"--></p>  
 <%
 else
 %><p><!--#include file="header_a.asp"--></p><%
 End If
 %>
<!--
<table width="100%" style="border-left-width: 0; border-top-width: 0; border-bottom-width: 0">
  <tr>
    <td width="24%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="border-top:medium none #111111; border-bottom:medium none #111111; border-left-style:none; border-left-width:medium; border-right-style:none; border-right-width:medium" height="25">&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <center> <img border="0" height=90 width=312 src="images/tulipconnect12.jpg">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</center> </td>

  </tr>
</table>

<table width="100%"  style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#FFCC99" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="20%" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1" align="center" bordercolor="#FFFFFF" bgcolor="#F37D7D">
    <b><font color="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; </font>
    <font color="#006699" face="Verdana" size="2"> 
    <a style="color: #FFFFFF" href="view_list.asp">Home</a></font></b></td>
    <td width="20%" bgcolor="#F37D7D" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1" align="center" bordercolor="#FFFFFF">
    <p align="center"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;<font face="Verdana" size="2" color="#FFFFFF"> View-Calls</font></b></td>
    <td width="20%" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1" align="center" bordercolor="#FFFFFF" bgcolor="#F37D7D">
    <b><font color="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </font>
    <font face="Verdana" color="#FF6600">
    <a href="changepassword.asp"><font size="2" color="#FFFFFF">Change</font></a></font><font face="Verdana"><font size="2"><a style="color: #FFFFFF" href="changepassword.asp"> 
    Password</a></font><font color="#FF6600"><a href="changepassword.asp"><font size="2" color="#FFFFFF">
    </font> </a>
    </font></font></b></td>
    <td width="20%" bgcolor="#F37D7D" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1" align="center" bordercolor="#FFFFFF">
    <p align="center">
    <b>
    <font color="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;<font face="Verdana" size="2">&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="down.ASP">
    <font color="#FFFFFF">Downtime Report</font></a></font></font></b></td>
    <td width="20%" bgcolor="#F37D7D" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1" align="center" bordercolor="#FFFFFF">
    <p align="center">
    <b>
    <font color="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;<font face="Verdana" size="2">&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="LOGOUT.ASP">
    <font color="#FFFFFF">Logout</font></a></font></font></b></td>

  </tr>
</table>
-->
<%
   if session("type1") =1 then
  end if
%>
   <center> 
     <font color="#F37D7D" face="Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif" size="4">&nbsp;</font><font color="#FF3300" face="Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif" size="3"><b>Circuit Closed Calls</b></font>
   </center>

<%
    dim name
   pno=request.querystring("page")
   name= request.form("engineer")
    if pno="" then
    pno=0
    end if 

'     set con =server.createobject("ADODB.CONNECTION")
     set rs=server.createobject("ADODB.RECORDSET")
 '    con.open "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source = database.tulipconnect.com\CALLMANAGER1; Initial Catalog = support; User Id = app; Password=App_access_2009"


     sql="select Fault_Ticket_Num,Organisation,Link_Location,Fault_Detail,dDate,tTime,cldate,Assigned_To from Call_Login  where Call_Status <> 'OPEN' and region='"&session("region")&"' order by dDate desc"


     rs.open sql,con


     %>





<table height="90%" align="center">
<tr>
<td valign="top">
    <table  width="95%" height="70" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#FFCC99" style="border-collapse: collapse">
  <tr bordercolor="FF3333" bgcolor="FF3333">
    <td width="6%" height="56" align="center" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1"><b><font face="Verdana" color="#FFFFFF" size="2">Call history</font></b></td>
    <td width="13%" height="56" align="center" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1"><font color="#FFFFFF" face="Verdana" size="2"><b>Fault Ticket Number</b></font></td>
    <td width="9%" height="56" align="center" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1"><b><font color="#ffffff" face="Verdana" size="2">Organization</font></b></td>
    <td width="8%" height="56" align="center" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1" ><b><font color="#FFFFFF" face="Verdana" size="2">&nbsp;Location</font></b></td>
    <td width="25%" height="56" align="center" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1"><b><font color="#ffffff" face="Verdana" size="2">Fault Details </font> </b> </td>
    <td width="10%" height="56" align="center" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1" ><b><font face="Verdana" color="#FFFFFF" size="2">Call Status</font></b></td>
    <td width="8%" height="56" align="center" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1" ><b><font face="Verdana" color="#FFFFFF" size="2">Assigned To</font></b></td>
    <td width="10%" height="56" align="center" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1" ><b><font color="#FFFFFF" face="Verdana" size="2">Opening Date</font></b></td>
    <td width="10%" height="56" align="center" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1" ><b><font color="#FFFFFF" face="Verdana" size="2">Closing Date</font></b></td>
  </tr>
  <% 
     If rs.eof Then
      response.write("No call for this user")
      response.End
      End if
      rs.move(10*pno)
      rno=0

      while not rs.eof and rno<10
       rno=rno+1

     %>
  <tr>
    <td width="6%" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1" bordercolor="#F37D7D" bgcolor="#F9EFF6" height="15"><center>
      <a href=fault_history.asp?reportid=<%=rs("Fault_Ticket_Num")%>&assignto=<%=rs("Assigned_To")%>> <img border="0" src="images/right_arrow.gif" width="13" height="13"></a>
    </center></td>
    <td width="12%" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1" align="center" bgcolor="#F9EFF6" bordercolor="#F37D7D" height="15"><font color="blue" face="verdana" size=2><%=rs("Fault_Ticket_Num")%></font></td>
    <td width="9%" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1" align="center" bgcolor="#F9EFF6" bordercolor="#F37D7D" height="15"><font color="blue" face="verdana" size=2><%=rs("Organisation")%></font></td>
    <td width="8%" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1" align="center" bgcolor="#F9EFF6" bordercolor="#F37D7D" height="15"><font color="blue" face="verdana" size=2><%=rs("Link_Location")%></font></td>
    <td width="25%" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1" align="center" bgcolor="#F9EFF6" bordercolor="#F37D7D" height="15"><font color="blue" face="verdana" size=2><%=rs("Fault_Detail")%></font><font color="blue" face="verdana"> </font></td>
    <td width="10%" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1" align="center" bgcolor="#F9EFF6" bordercolor="#F37D7D" height="15"><font color="blue" face="verdana" size=2>
      <% response.write("Call Closed")%>
    </font><font color="blue" face="verdana"> </font>&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="8%" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1" align="center" bgcolor="#F9EFF6" bordercolor="#F37D7D" height="15">&nbsp;<font color="blue" face="verdana" size=2><%=rs("Assigned_To")%></font><font color="blue" face="verdana"> </font></td>
    <td width="10%" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1" align="center" bgcolor="#F9EFF6" bordercolor="#F37D7D" height="15"><font color="blue" face="verdana" size=2><%=rs("dDate")%></font></td>
    <td width="10%" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1" align="center" bgcolor="#F9EFF6" bordercolor="#F37D7D" height="15"><font color="blue" face="verdana" size=2><%=rs("clDate")%></font></td>
  </tr>
  <%   rs.movenext
    wend 
   %>
  <tr>
    <td width="20%" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1" align="center" bgcolor="#F9EFF6" bordercolor="white" height="15" colspan="7">
    <p align="left">
    <a style="color: #663399; font-family:verdana; font-size:12px" href="view_close.asp?D1=<%=oth%>&page=<%response.write(0)%>">First</a>
    <font color="#F37D7D">
      <%  if pno>0 then 
 %>
      </font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
       <a  style="color: #663399; font-family:verdana; font-size:12px" href="view_close.asp?D1=<%=oth%>&page=<%response.write(pno-1)%>">Previous</a><font color="#F37D7D">
        <% end if %>
        <%
if rno=10 Then
pno=pno+1 
  %>
        </font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a style="color:#663399; font-family:verdana; font-size:12px" href="view_close.asp?D1=<%=oth%>&page=<%response.write(pno)%>">Next</a><font color="#F37D7D">
          <% end if%>
        </font></p></td>
    <td width="20%" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1" align="center" bgcolor="#F9EFF6" bordercolor="white" height="15" colspan="2"><p><a href="view_open_excel.asp"><font color="black" size="2">MOVE TO EXCEL</font></a> </p></td>
  </tr>
</table>

  </form>





<%
   pno1=request.querystring("page1")

%>
   <center> 
     <p><font color="#F37D7D" face="Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif" size="4">&nbsp;</font><font color="#FF3300" face="Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif" size="3"><b>POP Closed Call</b></font></p>
     </center>
    <% 

   Set rs_pop =server.CreateObject("adodb.recordset")
   sql_pop_calls="Select distinct(location_b),call_status,fault_detail,ddate,cldate from call_login where pop_call='Y' and call_status='CLOSE' group by  location_b,circuit_id,fault_detail,ddate,call_status,cldate"
    'response.write(sql_pop_calls)
        rs_pop.open sql_pop_calls ,con  %>

  <table  width="95%" height="70" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#FF3300" bgcolor="#FFF0F4" style="border-collapse: collapse">
  <tr bgcolor="FF3333">
  <td width="5%" height="40" bordercolor="#EED5D5" style="border-style: none; border-width: 1">
<b><font face="Verdana" color="#FFFFFF" size="2">S.NO.</font></b></td>
<td width="10%" height="40" bordercolor="#EED5D5" style="border-style: none; border-width: 1">
<b><font face="Verdana" color="#FFFFFF" size="2">POP Name</font></b></td>
    <td width="19%" height="40" align="left" bordercolor="#EED5D5" style="border-style: none; border-width: 1">
    <font color="#FFFFFF" face="Verdana" size="2"><b>Fault Details</b></font></td>
    <td width="15%" height="40" align="left" bordercolor="#EED5D5" style="border-style: none; border-width: 1">
    <b><font color="#FFFFFF" face="Verdana" size="2">Opening Date</font></b></td>
    <td width="15%" height="40" align="left" bordercolor="#EED5D5" style="border-style: none; border-width: 1">
    <b><font color="#FFFFFF" face="Verdana" size="2">Closing Date</font></b></td>
    <td width="13%" height="40" align="left" bordercolor="#EED5D5" style="border-style: none; border-width:1" >
    <b><font color="#FFFFFF" face="Verdana" size="2">No. of Affected Circuits</font></b></td>
  </tr>
    <%
    if pno1="" then
    pno1=1
    end if 
    if pno1=1 then
    sno=0
    else
    sno=(pno1-1)*10
    end if

      rs_pop.move(10*pno1)
      rno=0

    'sno=0
        if not rs_pop.eof then
            do while not rs_pop.eof and rno<10
            rno=rno+1

            sno=sno+1
            %>
            <tr>
            <td align="center"><font color="blue" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">
            <%=sno%></font>         </td>
            <td>
            <font color="blue" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2"><%=rs_pop("location_b")%></font>           </td>
            <td><font color="blue" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2"><%=rs_pop("fault_detail")%></font></td>
            <td><font color="blue" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2"><%=rs_pop("ddate")%><%'=rs_pop("ddate")%></font></td>
            <td><font color="blue" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2"><%=rs_pop("cldate")%><%'=rs_pop("ddate")%></font></td>
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <% 
            set rs_count_fault=server.CreateObject("adodb.recordset")
            sql_count_fault="select count(circuit_id) as no_of_faults from call_login where ddate='"&rs_pop("ddate")&"' and pop_call='Y' and call_status='CLOSE' and location_b='"&rs_pop("location_b")&"' group by location_b "
            'response.Write(sql_count_fault)
            rs_count_fault.open sql_count_fault,con
            if not rs_count_fault.eof then %>
            <a href="#" onClick="javascript:imgB('pop_call_effected_cir_list.asp?pop_name=<%=rs_pop("location_b")%>&call_status=<%=rs_pop("call_status")%>&d_date=<%=rs_pop("ddate")%>')" title="View Affected Circuits">
            <font color="blue" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2"><%=rs_count_fault("no_of_faults")%></font></a>

            <%
            end if
            %>          </td>
            </tr>

        <%  rs_pop.movenext
            loop
        else
        %>
        <tr><td colspan="6"><font color="#000099" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="1"><b>No Open Calls </b></font></td></tr>
        <%
        end if  

        %>

       <tr><td width="20%" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1" align="center" bgcolor="#F9EFF6" bordercolor="white" height="15" colspan="7"> 
   <p align="left"><a style="color: #663399; font-family:verdana; font-size:12px" href="view_close.asp?page1=<%response.write(1)%>">First</a><font color="#F37D7D">
  <%  if pno1>1 then 
 %>    
    </font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <a style="color: #663399; font-family:verdana; font-size:12px" href="view_close.asp?page1=<%response.write(pno1-1)%>">Previous</a><font color="#F37D7D">
      <% end if %>
      <%
if rno=10 Then
pno1=pno1+1 
  %> 
        </font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a style="color: #663399; font-family:verdana; font-size:12px" href="view_close.asp?page1=<%response.write(pno1)%>">Next</a><font color="#F37D7D">
      <% end if%></font></p></td></tr>
</table>
<br>
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
  <!--#include file="footer.asp"-->


  <script>
 function imgB(useridVal)
{
    urlImg=useridVal;
    nwin1 = window.open(urlImg,"imgB","toolbar=no,directories=no, scrollbars=1, resizable=1,menubar=no,location=no,maximize=yes,width=450,height=230");
}
function boxes()
{
    if(f1.C2.checked==true)
    {
       for(i=0;i<f1.C1.length;i++)
       document.f1.C1[i].checked=true
    }
   if(f1.C2.checked==false)
    {
       for(i=0;i<f1.C1.length;i++)
       document.f1.C1[i].checked=false
    }
}
function Delete()
{
   if(confirm("Are you sure"))
   return true
   else 
   return false

   }

</script>
      </font>   </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Posting large code sample without any explanation is bad. Your comment isn't clear at all. Some of content is irrelevant to the question. It's better to explain in words what you're trying to advice and post only the necessary code.