# Paging and saving the values of checkboxes

Tags: html, sql, vbscript, asp-classic

I'm using paging which uses a stored procedure to filter by letter. I need to save the values of checkboxes as I submit the form as I filter by letter. I have had a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280719/pagination-classic-asp-and-button-changed-to-hyperlinks) similar to this which worked great but I want to be able to keep my stored procedure.

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[A_Page_Paging]
@selected_Char char(1) = null,
@permissionID int = null
as
if @permissionID = ''
    if @selected_Char = '#'
            select * from A_Page where P_Description like '[^a-z]%'
    else if @selected_Char = '!'
            select * from A_Page
            order by P_Description
    else
            select * from A_Page where P_Description like @selected_Char + '%'
else
    select P_PageID, P_Name, P_Description from A_Permission
    inner join L_PagePermission
    on P_PermissionID = PP_PermissionID
    inner join A_Page
    on P_PageID = PP_PageID
    where P_PermissionID = @permissionID
    order by P_Name
```

Paging buttons:

```
<input id="buttonStyle" type="submit" name="Paging_Button" value="#">
<% for i = 97 to 122 %>
    <input id="buttonStyle" type="submit" name="Paging_Button" value="<%=CHR(i) %>">&nbsp;
<% next %>
<input id="buttonStyle" type="submit" name="Paging_Button" value="All">
```

Function to save checkboxes and checkbox (the function will only work for example if I select a checkbox with the value starting with A then filter by A the checkbox will show, if I filter by B it wont):

```
   'Checkbox check
        Function CheckedByUser(id)
            Dim x
            CheckedByUser = "checked=""checked"""
            For x=1 To Request.Form("selectedRecord").Count
                If Trim(Request.Form("selectedRecord").Item(x)) = Trim(id) Then
                    Exit Function
                End If
            Next
            CheckedByUser = ""
        End Function

<input type="checkbox" name="selectedRecord" value="<%=objRS("P_PageID")%>" <%=CheckedByUser(objRS("P_PageID")) %>>
```

Previous answer to fix paging problem but requires me to change my stored procedure which i prefer not to do:

```
<%
Do Until objRS.EOF
    Response.Write("<input type=""checkbox"" name=""selectedRecord"" value=""" & objRS("Id") & """ " & WasCheckedByUser(objRS("Id")))
    If Len(Request.Form("Page"))=1 And Trim(Left(objRS("Id"), 1))<>Trim(Request.Form("Page")) Then
        Response.Write(" style=""display: none;""")
    End If
    Response.Write(" />")
    objRS.MoveNext
Loop
%>
```

Executing stored procedure

```
connectionstring = obj_ADO.getconnectionstring
Set objCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
set objComm = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
objCon.Open connectionstring

objComm.ActiveConnection = objCon.ConnectionString
objComm.CommandText = "A_Page_Paging"
objComm.CommandType = 4


Set objParameter = objComm.CreateParameter
objParameter.Name = "selected_Char"
objParameter.Type = 129
objParameter.Direction = 1
objParameter.Size = 3
objParameter.Value = Selected_Button
objComm.Parameters.Append objParameter

Set objParameter2 = objComm.CreateParameter
objParameter2.Name = "PermissionID"
objParameter2.Type = 129
objParameter2.Direction = 1
objParameter2 .Size = 3
objParameter2 .Value = P_ID
objComm.Parameters.Append objParameter2

set objRS = objComm.Execute
```

Comment: Simply call the stored procedure `A_Page_Paging` passing only `!` as the first parameter, instead of passing the selected letter. Post the code where you execute the stored procedure in the ASP code if want further help.

Comment: @shadowwizard I added the code you requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line in your code:

```
objParameter.Value = Selected_Button
```

To this instead:

```
objParameter.Value = "!"
```

The code you already have in the loop should hide the checkboxes that are not part of the current  "page".

Comment: How can I filter by anything but a letter which i used with # in my stored procedure?

Comment: @kurupt Not sure what is the use of this, you can simply have `objParameter.Value = "#"`